# How to use variable in regex?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, bash

How do I replace `regex` with `$var` in this command?

```
echo "$many_lines" | sed -n '/regex/{g;1!p;};h'
```

`$var` could look like `fs2@auto-17`.

The `sed` command will output the line immediately before a regex, but not the line containing the regex.

If all this can be done easier with a Perl one-liner, then it is fine with me.

Comment: `echo $many_lines` won't work the way you expect unless you quote: `echo "$many_lines"`

Comment: Please improve your question by posting all relevant **error messages** exactly as they appear, and whatever **input samples** you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This can with all probability be done easier and better in perl. However, since you don't describe what you are trying to do, and I don't understand that `sed` code, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not beautiful, but this gives me the previous line to `$var` which is want I wanted.

```
echo "$many_lines" | grep -B1 "$var" | grep -v "$var"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl regexes, you can interpolate variable contents into regexes like `/$foo/`. However, the contents will be interpreted as a pattern. If you want to match the literal content of `$foo`, you have to escape the metacharacters: `$safe = quotemeta $foo; /$safe/`. This can be shortended to `/\Q$foo\E/`, which is what you usually want. A trailing `\E` is optional.

I don't know if the sed regex engine has a similar feature.

A Perl one-liner: `perl -ne'$var = "..."; print $p if /\Q$var/; $p=$_'`

Comment: ... and if the variable is an environment variable the way to access it is through the [`%ENV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25ENV) variable. `$ENV{PATH}`

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes to allow variable expansion:

```
echo $many_lines | sed -n "/$var/"'{g;1!p;};h'
```

Comment: If I do that in the terminal and press arrow up, it is turned into `"/$var/{g;1ps -p 1779;};h"` and the error `invalid command code f`

Comment: Take care that `$var` does not contain any unescaped forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a line before the regex, with a single one liner it will not be that trivial and beautiful, but here is how I will do it (Using Perl only):

`echo "$many_lines" | perl -nle 'print $. if /\Q$var/' | while read line_no; do 
    export line_no 

    echo $many_lines | perl -nle 'print if $. - 1 == $ENV{line_no}'

done`

or if you want to do in one line

`echo "$many_lines" | perl -nle 'BEGIN {my $content = ""; } $content .= $_; END { while ($content =~ m#([^\n]+)\n[^\n]+\Q$var#gosm) { print $1 }}'`

Or this one, should definitely match:

`echo "$many_lines" | perl -nle 'BEGIN {my @contents; } push @contents, $_; if ($contents[-1] =~ m#\Q$var#o)') { print $contents[-2] if defined  $contents[-2]; }`

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use here-documents too, if you don't want to escape the double quotes!

In Perl it looks like this:

```
$heredoc = <<HEREDOC;
  here is your text and $var is your parameter
HEREDOC
```

Its important to end the heredoc with the same string you began, in my example its "HEREDOC" in a new line!